# how to Select data from django tables and insert them to an another external database in use?

Tags: python, django, database

i have some data in Django database and i want to select them and copy them to an other external database in use  the structure of tables in Django database and in external database is same
i hope find any help please for make this logic ,thank you

Comment: Please specify which database is it?

Comment: iwant to copy bills from postgres django database to an external simple postgres database  ( the structure of tables are same )

Answer (score 0):

If the data is the same, you should export it through the database directly. Assuming you are using PostgreSQL (According to the comments):

```
pg_dump --table=YOUR_TABLE_NAME --data-only --column-inserts YOUR_DATABASE_NAME > data.sql
```

Then on the receiving database,

```
psql {YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING} < data.sql
```

Comment: yes but i want make transfert button in django app for copy bills to the other external database you understand me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the process via a button, I would recommend that you use Aayush's code within a django view that is called by your button. If the transfer takes too much time to wait for the site to refresh afterwarda, you can call the view via ajax or you can call the script as a parallel process via the view.

Comment: i understand little your idea but what is Aayush's code ?? and if i use ajax how i can insert in external database with ajax ??